Socket error 10060 Mdaemon connection timed out
I have had a problem on my Mdaemon mail server for several days, no external mail arrives, but they do go out without a problem. I have all ports open on my Pfsense for the mail server and the firewall disabled. This happened to me when I changed ISP and changed my DNS server.When I check my DNS it seems fine
I need help please.

You've spammed tags which have nothing to do with your question. Voting for close, as completely off-topic-
